# Sharing content/apps between console and VNC console

Tags: remote, vnc, desktop-environment

I have a linux box that I use a lot from my Mac laptop (1920x1200 resolution screen) via VNC.  At work, I have a dual-monitor setup for the Linux Box (1600x1200 each monitor).  I use the VNC connection to provide a "persistent" desktop for my work.  However, when I get to work (rarely, it seems), I'd like to pick up those projects that I have been working on in the desktop console.  I haven't found an easy way to "migrate" from the VNC to the desktop.  Is that technically possible?  Any suggestions on how this can be done or what you do to accomplish a similar effect of having a "persistent" environment would be great to hear.

Comment: It sounds like you have multiple desktops on this system and one is being used by the VNC connection while the other is being used by the console, can you confirm this?

Comment: That is my current setup, yes.

Comment: Wouldn't you rather have a single desktop that you're accessing from either console or VNC? Or do you want to continue to keep this setup?

Comment: I want the same console, but I have 1600x1200 on two monitors on the physical connection and my laptop is 1920x1200.

Comment: How have you setup VNC? Are you using x11vnc? See these Q's for more details on it: http://unix.stackexchange.com/search?q=x11vnc+user%3A7453